# Rails 5: Autoloading with custom folders not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this class:

```
# app/events/new_request.rb
class Events::NewRequest
end
```

And I added that folder to the autoload:

```
# config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths += %W( events/ )
```

And when running `rails c`:

```
> Events::NewRequest
NameError: uninitialized constant Events
```

The thing is that if I don't use the namespace "Events" when defining the class, it autoloads the class successfully.

Comment: Everything under `app` is loaded automatically, so you should not have to add it to the autoload paths

Comment: @Iceman Well, if I remove that, It still doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: It's because `events` folder is a root or whatever the terminology is, I tried it and got it working by doing `app/events/events/new_request.rb`

Comment: You could also place it under `models/events/new_request.rb`

Comment: Try restarting the rails server. If you are using spring then run `spring stop` and then start the server. I don't remember exactly why but sometimes the rails autoloader does not pickup when you create a new directory. I have lost much hair over this.

Comment: @max I already tried to run `spring stop` and run the rails console again. Still getting the error.

Comment: @Iceman Have you tried that with Rails 5? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Yes, just tried with Rails 5.1.0

Comment: @Iceman So you created the class here app/events/new_request.rb and defined it like this: class Events::NewRequest, and it works?

Comment: There is a workaround to get the autoloader to load  `Events:: NewRequest ` from `app/events/new_request.rb` that I used when defining services a while back. I'll have to see if I can dig it up.

Comment: @Iceman is correct and Rails version doesn't matter it would be `app/anything_in_app/events` generally works best if you add an `events.rb` in `anything_in_app` folder even if the `Module` or `Class` is empty as it helps `Autoload` declare the name space.

Comment: No, as I said I created `app/events/events/new_request.rb` and got that working

Comment: @Iceman But can't I do it without two folders with the same name? I don't see the point...

Comment: `config.autoload_paths += [config.root.join('app')]`  is the workaround.

Comment: Like @engineersmnky said, it's just a coincidence it's two folders with the same name, the general thinking is `app/some_folder_name/namespace/class.rb`

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes, I know, I was re-agreeing, if that is a word, and it probably isn't.

Answer (score 3):

```
module Sandbox
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += [config.root.join('app')]
  end
end
```

This will let Rails autoload `Events::NewRequest` from `app/events/new_request.rb`.

```
irb(main):001:0> Events
=> Events
irb(main):002:0> Events::NewRequest
=> Events::NewRequest
```

Comment: I'm not even sure exactly why this works - its something with the way the autoloading paths are setup so the ignore the first directory under `app` as a module nesting. But I have not encountered any real issues with this hack so far.

Comment: Seems contrived and confusing as to why these are namespaced and other classes are not eg `Controllers::ApplicationController` better to follow convention or require explicitly in my opinion

Comment: I agree with you there @engineersmnky. This demonstrates that it is possible. Not that its a good idea :D

Comment: @blinc - edit posts to clarify or improve grammar, spelling or formatting. Do not edit to add code to others answers that is not tested and does not produce the correct results!